# How to call an extension directly from outside with Asterisk?

Tags: voip, asterisk

How can I call an extension from outside directly without using a voice menu?

For example I am calling a number xxx-xxxxxxx and the extension is 2002. I have not setup an voicemenu type thing with Asterisk, but I still want to be able to access to extension 2002(or another) from an external call?

My external calls normally goto 2001.

Comment: Do you want to always go to 2002, or do you want some kind of menu/trigger that would forward the call to 2002?

Comment: Hi I do not always goto 2002 naturally. I just want to be able to call the extention when I needed. I also do not want to setup some kind of menu system since this is really a home number

Comment: Do you have FreePBX installed, and do you have access to make configuration changes?

Comment: What is it currently configured to do? (Please update your question)

Comment: I doubt you would be able to dial `xxx-xxxxxxx2002` directly from the outside because your provider would 'swallow' up the `2002` (or your provider must support sending the extra digits after a connection is made). You might be able to setup a 'silent'-menu (with a beep or something) after which you would be able to dial `2002` after you get a connection.

Comment: @Oxymoron, right now all the calls goto extension 2001 automaticall. If that one does not answer it is directed to another extension, which terminates there. I have FreePbx installed with AsteriskNOw. I have access to all the setup